# grep to match two occurrences of the same pattern with a certain number of characters in between

Tags: macos, regex, grep

I have a text file, `test` that contains the following string

```
MDXXXXXMD
```

though in general, `X` could be any character and `M` could also be `F`. I'm trying to select for this string with the following `grep` command:

```
grep '\(F\|M\)D.{,5}\(F\|M\)D' test
```

However, this does not return anything, meaning that the regex cannot select for the string. The `\(F\|M\)D` part works fine:

```
➜  ~ grep '\(F\|M\)D' test
MDXXXXXMD
```

Doesn't `.{,5}` mean up to 5 occurences of any character? What am I missing?

(I'm on mac if that makes a difference)

Comment: Yes, it makes a difference. Linux has GNU grep, MacOS has BSD grep. There are a number of differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a Mac I would try with `{0,5}` instead of an empty entry (`{,5}`). Because the empty entry is a GNU extension which may not be supported on the Mac.

Also, just like with the other regex characters, the `{` and `}` should be escaped `\{0,5\}` should work best.

If the `0` is an issue (invalid count), then you can make it with an extra set of parenthesis:

```
\(.\{1,5\}\)\?
```

That means those 1 to 5 characters are optional.

Comment: ah, the addition of the lower limit turns out to be critical for mac! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be escaping also the brackets:

```
grep '\(F\|M\)D.\{,5\}\(F\|M\)D' test
```

Comment: I get an error that says `grep: invalid repetition count(s)`.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu with `echo MDXXXXXMD | grep '\(F\|M\)D.\{,5\}\(F\|M\)D'`. What is your operating system?

Comment: macos. turns out I needed to add a lower limit (see the other answer).